# Finishing an Activity with transition shows the previous Activity from the activity stack first and then transitions to the new Activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

I have 2 Activities in my Android application - Activity A and Activity B.
When the user presses a button on Activity A, he is navigated to Activity B.
I want Activity A to close after going to the next activity and is completely removed from the activity stack.
I tried adding `intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);` , but this not work as Activity A was still accessible after pressing the back button.

I added `finishAffinity();` , this worked, but while transitioning, the previous activity in the activity stacks gets visible and then it goes to Activity B.

Video
(here the application drawer is shown, and then it goes to Activity B) -

[image]

Code -

```
ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(MainActivity.this);
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity2.class);
startActivity(i, options.toBundle());
finishAffinity();
```

Any fix so that the previous activity is not visible and activity is also closed ?

---

**EDIT :**  I tried `finish()`, `finishAfterTransition()` and `supportFinishAfterTransition()` instead of `finishAffinity()` but still the previous screen is visible.
So I guess there's an issue with `finishAfterTransition()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by adding `android:noHistory="true"` attribute to the activity (which has to be removed from the stack) in the manifest file solves the issue.
There is no need to use `finish()` in the java code after this change.

Method 2 -
Refer @Pratyay ' s answer for a way around.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        finishAffinity();
    }
```

Use this function in Activity B, this will exit app on pressing back button. And don't use any `finish();` or `finishAffinity();` in Activity A. This will give a smooth transition

Comment: This does not solve the issue. Even after using `finish()` the previous screen is visible.

Comment: Got it ! Thanks, refer to the way around I got below too. This method would increase the memory used by the app as Activities would pile up, and can not be done always (For ex. if we do not want to close the Activity on Back press).

Answer (score 0):

you have to use finish but like this:

```
startActivity(Your Activity here)
```

then `Finish()`
if you do reverse you can see black screen for a short time do this way

Comment: Hi, I have done this only, please see the code above